# How to fix computer-specific, phantom IntelliSense errors in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, intellisense

First post ever, so feel free to offer critiques or advice.

**Disclaimer** - I have already tried the following:

- Deleted .vs and .suo
- Repaired Visual Studio
- Matched Windows SDK and solution target to 10.0.17763.0, 10.0.17134.0, and 10.0.15063.0
- Made sure that I have installed all corresponding SDK's on my machine
- Cleaned solution, cleared browser database errors
- Set Include Directories to inherit from parent
- EDIT 2: Recloned repository on laptop

**Issue**:

On my **laptop**, I have hundreds of phantom IntelliSense errors, mainly comprised of things similar to "cannot open source file 'stdio.h'", "cannot open source file 'vector'", "namespace 'std' has no member 'vector'", "namespace 'std' has no member 'string'". **Everything compiles** and runs but this is incredibly annoying.

To the best of my knowledge, I have no issues with include statements. There were no issues of any kind for the longest time. They showed up seemingly randomly, but obviously I must have done something.

If I clone the same repo on my **desktop**, or pull changes, there are no IntelliSense issues.

EDIT: Including actual question...

**Question**: Does anyone have any other ideas besides what I have included that could solve this issue?

Comment: Have you also tried deleting the intellisense database file for the project? I forget what extension is has in VS2017, but in VS2015 it's a .VC.db

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The vc.db is actually inside the .vs folder, that I could find. So I believe that deleting the .vs deletes the database as well.

Comment: Hi, please go to File-New-Project-Other Project Types-Visual Studio Solutions and create a new blank solution, then add your projects into it to have a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue!

It was due to issues in my Additional Include Directories and Linker. I was trying to include SDL on both my desktop and laptop (two different locations) in order to save the bore of changing the include every time I develop on a different machine. This caused the intellisense errors on just my laptop because my includes for SDL on my desktop were listed first, or at least that is my assumption.

Thank you all or the help!